# Mint Cinnamon rendering issues after unknown changes

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

The other night I shut down my machine with everything looking 'normal'. Now I am having issues with no borders around things, glitches, and had to go to Konsel because gnome terminal was un-readable.

Expected Output:
[image]

My output:

[image]

Comment: Can you purge and reinstall the cinnamon packages?

Comment: I tried, but didn't seem to fix it

Comment: Which command did you run exactly? And what happened when you did?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove cinnamon

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge cinnamon`, then restart, then `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`

Comment: Will do. I will post how it goes.

Comment: So I completely removed Cinnamon, and reinstalled it, and same errors. It some how kept my config tho...

Comment: After the purge?

Comment: Correct. I was just going to add gnome, but it is not working.

Comment: Do you have any config files in your home directory?

Comment: Yes I do.. should I delete them?

Comment: My guess is that some of them are related to cinnamon, try deleting those and purging again, and see if your configuration remains after a reinstall